# Touch focus recognition in android

Tags: android, touch, focus, floating-action-button

In my android studio, I am creating animated floating  button, in which on click it expands to multiple floating button again on click it collapse. "https://www.sitepoint.com/animating-android-floating-action-button/"

The part where I need help is if the buttons are expanded and the user instead of collapsing the button its touches another part of the screen or clicks something else then I can detect and collapse it programmatically.

What method should i use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use third-party library to save your time. I recommend this [one](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)

Check it out and I hope that it will be useful

Comment: Some modification in my given example please